# android playlist, storing mp3 file in the app or calling url

Tags: java, android, mp3, audio-player, android-music-player

i'm actually adding a music player in my android app. It will contains 8 albums, 12songs in each one. So i'm thinking about the best way to do this. Should i store the mp3 songs in the app, which will make there lecture faster and won't need access to internet. Or maybe it's too much heavy and calling mp3 url would be a better idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to consider when evaluating your options.

If you ship the songs together with the app, you will greatly increase it's size. Most probably you will go over the 50 Mb limit, and you will have to implement APK expansion files, which are downloaded when the app is first started. Implementing this is not very hard, but it can take some time.

If you implement a custom download for the songs, you can optionally provide better control over what is downloaded, optimizing bandwidth usage, download times, etc. Still, it would be more difficult to implement then the standard APK expansions, and you will have to deal with a lot of additional download logic - pausing / resuming, dealing with insufficient storage space, etc.

My advice is to go with an APK expansion, which is downloaded when the app is first started and will manage all the download complexity out of the box. If you need a more fine grained download - go custom.

Good luck.

Comment: and passing by mp3 url is a bad idea, isn't it?

Comment: I would say yes, it would require a lot of bandwidth, it will have problems over poor connections... I would definitely not recommend it.